# How can I merge two Doubles together?

Tags: double, swiftui

SwiftUI ... Having troubles with how to use variables...

I have two Binding Variables as Doubles.

```swift
struct DisplayCalc : View {
    @Binding var mhzValue : Double
    @Binding var mhzValueStep : Double
}
```

Example:
mzhValue is 7.00

mhzValueStep is say 9.40

I would like to set a new variable say newVariable = 7.940

Any suggestions ?

Thank you..
Craig

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it easily by right shifting the value(assuming it will be positive) until it is less than 1. For this purpose you can use an extension of Double. Here is a code that will serve your purpose.

```swift
struct ContentView : View {
    var mhzValue : Double = 7.000
    var mhzValueStep : Double = 102.200

    private var mySum: Double { mhzValue + mhzValueStep.getMinimalDouble() }

    var body: some View {
        Text("My sum is \(self.mySum)")
    }
}

extension Double {
    func getMinimalDouble() -> Double {
        var value = self
        while(value >= 1.0) {
            value /= 10.0
        }
        return value
    }
}
```

Comment: Great work... that did the trick... There are some clever people here.. Not me I'm afraid.. thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this :

```swift
struct DisplayCalc : View {
    @Binding var mhzValue : Double
    @Binding var mhzValueStep : Double

    private var mySum: Double { mhzValue + mhzValueStep }

    var body: some View {
         Text("My sum is \(self.mySum)")
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi.. thank you...  however using your code, I get the wrong result.. using a value of mhzValue 7.000 & mhzValueStep 102.200, I was hoping to get 7.102, however I am getting 109.2000.  Not sure why ??? Cheers.. Craig

Comment: Because 7000 + 102200 = 109200 :-) Use the correct locales when converting from String (I assume) to Double, you expect the `.` to be the decimal separator while it is the thousands separator.

Comment: Yes.. I see.. is there a way to turn each Double to a String, so i end up with a String of 7.00 and String 9.40, then manipulate the Strings to make 7.940 then convert that to a Double or Float ?? Thanking your advance... Craig